# how to use array in uiview animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a UIView Animation, my array contains 10 images.  I want to move one place to another place when button is pressed. Below code is working but problem is all 10 images is moving.

```
-(IBAction)moveImageAtIndex:(int)index {
    UIButton *buttonCelebrate = [redAppleArray objectAtIndex:j];
    UIButton *buttonRefer = [reffButtonArray objectAtIndex:j];

    currentView = buttonCelebrate;
    CGRect frame = currentView.frame;
    CGRect frame1 = buttonRefer.frame;

    frame.origin.x = frame1.origin.x;
    frame.origin.y = frame1.origin.y;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    currentView.frame = frame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^
     {
         [currentView setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];

     }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         if (finished) {
             if(index != [redAppleArray count] - 1) {
                 [self moveImageAtIndex:index+1];
              }
         }
     }];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
 }
```

Expected Output is: I want to move one by one instead of all.

[screenshot](http://imageshack.com/a/img202/5695/ez76.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the code from loop and keep in the method which is called by button then by pressing the button your images in array will be moved one by one according to user clicks.

declare i as int in the .h file and make i value as 0 in viewDidLoad and Don't forget to increment the i value in the end

use below code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    i=0;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
-(IBAction)methodName:(id)sender {

    UIButton *buttonCelebrate = [redAppleArray objectAtIndex:index];
    currentView = buttonCelebrate;
    CGRect frame = currentView.frame;
    CGRect frame1 = reffButton.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame1.origin.x;
    frame.origin.y = frame1.origin.y;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    currentView.frame = frame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^
    {
        [currentView setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];

     }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         if (finished) {

         }
     }];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    i++;
}
```

as per the Eric use below code

You have to wait until the current animation has finished, then you can start the next animation. A simple solution is to use recursion:

```
-(void)moveImageAtIndex:(int)index {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    UIButton *buttonCelebrate = [redAppleArray objectAtIndex:i];


    currentView = buttonCelebrate;

    CGRect frame = currentView.frame;
    CGRect frame1 = reffButton.frame;

    frame.origin.x = frame1.origin.x;
    frame.origin.y = frame1.origin.y;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    currentView.frame = frame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^
     {
         [currentView setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];

     }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         if (finished) {
            if(index != [redAppleArray count] - 1) {
                [self moveImageAtIndex:index + 1];
            }
         }
     }];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Why should the counter variable `i` be in the .h file? Why should it even be a property/ivar?

Comment: It works. But i want first value is moved and then second value is moved automatically and so on. what to do.

Comment: then use the @eric Qian answer that is recursive so after moving of one image another image will move .

Comment: i tried this if(j != [redAppleArray count] - 1) {
                 
             }

Comment: can you rewrite the program using @eric Qian answer

Comment: second is not moving.  Only one value is moving

Comment: now check it @user3069029 i have change some code if still getting problem please send your code to me i will do it n send it to u ashokdy@gmail.com

Comment: i sent a mail. please check it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait until the current animation has finished, then you can start the next animation. A simple solution is to use recursion:

```
-(void)moveImageAtIndex:(int)index {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
         //Do animation
     }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         if (finished) {
             if(index != [redAppleArray count] - 1) {
                  [self moveImageAtIndex:index + 1];
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: i tried, but it's not moving.  Only one value would be passed.

Comment: It should work, this piece of code is just give you a hint, you cannot just copy and paste it into your project, then build and run. You have to do more jobs by yourself especially when you do animation.

Comment: i change my code above.  could you tell me that is correct or not

Comment: OK, I found a problem. In your code, there are actually 3 animations. The second line starts an animation, and then `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];` is another animation. In side the second animation you start the third animation with `[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^`. We only need one animation here, so just think about it carefully.

Comment: no. i have multiple animation. i.e., i generate a random number.  if random number is 4, four images will move and so on.

Comment: But what you want is, these four images are moving one after another not at the same time, right?

Comment: Ok, why you need 3 animations

Comment: no i want 'n' no of animation when button is clicked. n = random number (1 to 9), i never said 3 animation it varies.

Comment: i creating a addition program.  first textfield contains some number and same as second text field. If i click that textfield i want to move images where number is shown in text field.

Comment: I am a bit confused now. Can you show me some screenshots so I can understand bit more

Comment: i post my screen shot check it out.

Comment: OK, the screenshot helps me understand a lot. And in this case, when you do animation you have to pass two parameters instead of one. The first parameter is the index of the first image you wanna move and the second parameter is how many images you wanna move. I will post a new answer to help you understand.

Comment: that +1 is given by me

Answer (score 0):

The new solution is:

```
-(void)moveImageStartAtIndex:(int)index withHowMany:(int)howMany{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
         //Do animation
     }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         if (finished) {
             if(howMany > 1) {
                  [self moveImageStartAtIndex:index + 1 withHowMany:howMany - 1];
             }
         }
   }];
}
```

Comment: howMany? what will give to hawMany? Whether it is my textfield

Comment: How many means how many apple you want to move, for example, in the screenshot that the first text field is three, so the `howMany` is 3. And the second text field is two, so the `howMany` is 2